# Asp.net Request.Url.AbsoluteUri return IP

Tags: asp.net, url

I've got problem:
When I use

```
 Request.Url.AbsoluteUri
```

to detect page url at runtime, I always get url with IP, although my site is deployed at adress: http://site.domain.com.
How can I get url with http://site.domain.com instead of server ip.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you want current page url then you can use

```
Request.Url.ToString()
```